# Put Link into json using hook (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have a question, i want to add this command line:

```
Cell: ({ row }) => <a href={row.original.lastName}>{row.original.lastName}</a>
```

into 'lastName',using hook in reactjs, for example:

Before:

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState(
[
  {
    id:'firstName',   
    Header: 'First Name',
    accessor: 'firstName',
  },

  {
    Header: 'Last Name',
    accessor: 'lastName',
   },
]
);
```

```
setColumns(???)
```

Result:

```
[
   {
     id:'firstName',   
     Header: 'First Name',
     accessor: 'firstName',
   },

   {
     Header: 'Last Name',
     accessor: 'lastName',
     Cell: ({ row }) => <a href={row.original.lastName}>{row.original.lastName}</a>
    },
 ]
```

Best regards
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find a small working solution as below. Please feel free to replace the button click with your side effect which can be an API call or any action side effect. Just for simplicity, I have used a button.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Row = ({ row }) => (
  <a href={row.original.lastName}>{row.original.lastName}</a>
);

function App() {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    {
      id: "firstName",
      Header: "First Name",
      accessor: "firstName"
    },

    {
      Header: "Last Name",
      accessor: "lastName"
    }
  ]);

  const createRowsForLastName = () => {
    const replaceColumnForLastName = columns.map(column => {
      if (column.accessor === "lastName") {
        return {
          ...column,
          Cell: <Row row={{ original: { lastName: "some name" } }} />
        };
      }

      return { ...column };
    });

    setColumns(replaceColumnForLastName);
  };

  console.log(columns);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={createRowsForLastName}>Create Row!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```